# Understanding Permissions in existing SharePoint site

Tags: permissions, out-of-the-box

I've recently joined a team, and been given responsibility for managing most of the SharePoint 2010 site and sub-sites (there are currently around 10 sub-sites I have access to, and this will be increasing). It looks like the Permissions are a bit of a mess, and this is something I wanted to clean up a bit before the site gets any more complicated.

There are a lot of users who have been given access individually as well as in groups, most of the sub-sites have disinherited permissions, and there are unique permissions set at item level as well as library level and site level.

Is there any way to get an overview of the different dependencies and permissions so I can get a clearer picture of what's going on? I would like to be able to consolidate all of the permissions given to individuals into groups, but make sure that I'm not accidentally deleting item level permissions. I have been going through the permissions site by site, but is there a way around going item by item?

There has been no documentation by previous users, and no overall planning or consistency in the past, it's just sort of evolved. Is there anything I can do to make unpicking all of this easier? Anything I should be especially careful of?

I have Full Control of most areas, although there is a sub-site I do not have access to (high level finance stuff) and there are some items I don't have access to within sub-sites I do have access to. I don't have access to the Server, or any custom tooling, I'm stuck with out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can ask Server administrators to export all site/subsite permissions to a file for you via PowerShell. Hope this link can help you.

http://johanmeyer.ukuvuma.co.za/2013/02/22/export-all-user-permissions-from-a-sharepoint-2010-site-to-csv/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll see if I can track someone down on Monday to help me out...